# Catch an Exception from ISupportIncrementalLoading interface

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

How can I catch Exception from `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface lets say I have something like this

```
    public class MyCollection : ObservableCollection<MyModel>, ISupportIncrementalLoading
{
    private int page = 1;
    public bool HasMoreItems { get { return page < 10; } }
    public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {           
        return LoadMoreItemsTaskAsync(count)
      .AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();

    }

    private async Task<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsTaskAsync(uint count)
    {
        //my code which can fail, if so
    throw new MyException("can not connect",404);
        return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = (uint)count };
    }

}
```

and now lets say Im calling it like that:

```
    try
    { 
        MyCollection _Collection = new MyCollection();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MyExceptionTextBox.Text = ex.Message;
    }
```

I think you can see what I want to do, so what im doing wrong?

EDIT1: 
Debugger highlights this line:

```
throw new MyException("can not connect",404);
```

as you can see my try-catch section doesnt handle this Exception.

Comment: your question is too confusing.....first, you are not calling anything, you are just creating instance of type MyCollection....you cannot throw exception from Interface because Interface does not have definition....Class that implements it, in your case MyCollection class will have to throw exception.....you call implemented methods and wrap those call in try catch...pretty much similar to normal try catch....where are you confused with this?

Comment: Yeah I mean instance. Anyway when Im trying to compile it and instance MyCollection class with hardcoded thrownig error this error isnt handled by my try-catch section, but by VS debbuger: "An exception of type MyException occurred in myapp.exe but was not handled in user code".

Comment: are you sure instance is not created anywhere else also in your code? try enabling CLR exception ...it will highlight the line where exception is occurred

Comment: Yeah Im sure, so any other ideas? CLR highlight this line in app.g.i.cs if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Comment: OK after enbling all types of exception in Debug/Exception Settings " throw new MyException("can not connect",404);" is now highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

With your example code you aren't doing really doing anything other than instantiate the object. The interface itself is not going to throw any errors as it's an interface. The errors will originate from your implementation.

As you have in your example simply encompass the calling code in a try/catch and you will catch the errors.

Perhaps some more information of your implementation could be provided?

Comment: Until a reputation of 50 is reached comments are not an option, bit of a chicken/egg scenario in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah I know........Then earn rep of 50 first but never post comment as answer.....That's what is suggested in Meta also....

Comment: After almost week of searching and trying to figure it by myself I have nothing. So I need to ask you for help once more. What is wrong with my code? To catch exception from IAsyncOperation you can call this operation like ' MyAsyncOperation().GetResults();' int try/catch block and thats it, but IDK how to catch exception from MyCollection which extends ISupportIncrementalLoading.